# Whats wrong with my For Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my For Loop. It generates my Button Images and display them.

Without my Delay, all is working. It is displayed instantly. But now i want to delay the loop, so that the animations are not started at the same time.

what i saw is, that my `NSLogs` are working as intended the `NSLogs` are displayed slowly with my delay.

but the Images are shown, when all `NSLogs` are finished. All at the same time. 
If i have 25 Buttons with 0.05 delay, all images are shown after 1,25 sec.

But i want to display after each 0.05 sec an image.

what am i doing wrong?

```
double secondsToSleepForLoop = .05;
for(int startingSquares = 0; startingSquares < _revealedSquares; startingSquares++) {
    int x = arc4random_uniform(5);
    int y = arc4random_uniform(5);

    if(buttons[x][y] == 0) {

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:secondsToSleepForLoop];

             NSLog(@"ADD");
             NSLog(@"x: %d", x);
             NSLog(@"y: %d", y);


        //ROW 1

        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            [UIView transitionWithView:_cell00
                              duration:.3
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{ [_cell00 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dot_%d.png", buttons[0][0]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            }];


        }
        if (x == 1 && y == 0) {
            [UIView transitionWithView:_cell10
                              duration:.3
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{ [_cell10 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dot_%d.png", buttons[1][0]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                            }];


and so on.... 
        }
```

Comment: You don't appear to understand that Cocoa Touch is an event based system and not letting the main thread process those events will cause the app to grind to a halt.

Comment: You're maybe interested with `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` which has a delay parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The animations won't begin until the current runloop cycle ends.  Your sleeping just delays the end of the runloop cycle.  I think you should try to `dispatch_after()` with a random delay instead.

Also, never, for *any* reason, sleep on the main thread.

Comment: plus 1 for ***never, for any reason, sleep on the main thread***